# RSpec not allowing nested argument matching with hash argument

Tags: ruby, rspec

I am trying to use RSpec's argument matching feature to ensure that a method gets called with a correct hash argument. Unfortunately, it seems that RSpec does not allow me to say something like `receive(:foo).with(instance_of(MyClass) => :bar, instance_of(MyClass) => :baz)`, presumably because the argument is a hash.

I tried to use the `including_hash` matcher to say `receive(:foo).with(hash_including(instance_of(MyClass) => :bar, instance_of(MyClass) => :baz))` but this does not work either.

Here is a reproduction of the problem:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require "rspec"

class Account
  def initialize(logger)
    @logger = logger
  end

  def open_with_hash_arg
    pipe_r, pipe_w = IO.pipe
    @logger.account_opened(pipe_r => :read, pipe_w => :write)
  end

  def open_with_flat_args
    pipe_r, pipe_w = IO.pipe
    @logger.account_opened(pipe_r, pipe_w)
  end
end

describe Account do
  it "fails with hash arg" do
    logger = double("Logger")
    expect(logger).to receive(:account_opened).with(instance_of(IO) => :read, instance_of(IO) => :write)
    account = Account.new(logger)
    account.open_with_hash_arg
  end

  it "succeeds with flat args" do
    logger = double("Logger")
    expect(logger).to receive(:account_opened).with(instance_of(IO), instance_of(IO))
    account = Account.new(logger)
    account.open_with_flat_args
  end
end
```

Here is the output of this program:

```
$ rspec ./tmp.rb
F.

Failures:

  1) Account fails with hash arg
     Failure/Error: @logger.account_opened(pipe_r => :read, pipe_w => :write)
     
       #<Double "Logger"> received :account_opened with unexpected arguments
         expected: ({an_instance_of(IO)=>:read, an_instance_of(IO)=>:write})
              got: ({#<IO:fd 5>=>:read, #<IO:fd 6>=>:write})
       Diff:
       @@ -1 +1 @@
       -[{an_instance_of(IO)=>:read, an_instance_of(IO)=>:write}]
       +[{#<IO:fd 5>=>:read, #<IO:fd 6>=>:write}]
       
     # ./tmp.rb:12:in `open_with_hash_arg'
     # ./tmp.rb:26:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.01154 seconds (files took 0.04986 seconds to load)
2 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./tmp.rb:22 # Account fails with hash arg
```

How can I use RSpec to test that a method is called with a hash argument where the keys are instances of some class?

Note that I am using RSpec version 3.11

Comment: I would strongly suggest flipping the keys and values e.g., (:read => pipe_r, :write => pipe_w).  Typically you would be trying to "name" the inputs with the hash.  From there, you could check into using `hash_including` to make sure the keys are correct.

Comment: This is not an option that will work for me unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Your method call is weird I was expecting it to be `@logger.account_opened(:read => pipe_r, :write => pipe_w)` so the hash key is the symbol and the value is the IO object. If that's the case you can use the following to test it.

```
expect(logger).to receive(:account_opened).with(:read => instance_of(IO), :write => instance_of(IO))
```